# does "low" is metaphorical here? like "inferior"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

does "low" is metaphorical here? like "inferior"?

Mr. P. B. Randall, in his biography of the Davenports (Boston 1869,
published anonymously), points out that their mission to England was
"to meet on its own **low** ground and conquer, by appropriate means, the
hard materialism and scepticism of England."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's metaphorical. It's used as the opposite of "high ground", as defined here:

[Merriam-Webster "high ground"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high%20ground)
a position of advantage or superiority especially : an ethically superior position
 *took the moral high ground during the debate*

Mr. Randall was saying that "materialism and scepticism" constitute a moral low ground to be conquered. It may also allude to "low ground" in the sense of an accessible military target.